# Installing Ubuntu 14.04--Grub Rescue Error after failing to turn off secure boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, grubrescue

Whenever I try to start my computer it shows the following error:

```
file /boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found 
Entering rescue mode... 
grub rescue>
```

I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 onto my computer which was preloaded with windows 8.1. My goal was to make this a dual boot.

I primarily followed [these instructions](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

I accidentally skipped step 5, which was turning off secure boot, and is most likely what led to my current error. Ubuntu installed on my computer but I was unable to run it past the live session which prompted me to try out Ubuntu and/or install it again. But now I can't even get there.

In frustration, I removed my flash drive and that is when I arrived at this screen, which I can't seem to get out of.

If helpful, entering the command `ls` on the grub rescue mode prompt outputs:

```
 (hd0) (hd0,gpt 12) (hd0,gpt 11) (hd0,gpt 10) (hd0,gpt 9) (hd0,gpt 8)... (hd0,gpt 2)
 (hd0,gpt 1)
```

`set` outputs:

```
cmdpath=(hd0) prefix=(hd0,gpt10)/boot/grub root=hd0,gpt10
```

These are the only two commands that work (that I know of). I've tried things like, `quit`, `exit`, `lsmod`, but none have worked.

Answer (score 1):

So I just now was able to successfully make my laptop a dual boot.

The way I got rid of the grub rescue prompt was actually by changing my boot mode from Legacy Mode to UEFI. I did this by booting into the bios menu when I turned on my computer by pressing f2 (for me). I then scrolled over to Boot and switched this under the Boot Mode option.

This got rid of the grub rescue screen upon powering up my machine. When I turned it on, it took me straight into Windows with no option to choose Ubuntu. My next step was to disable secure boot (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx for more info on this).

NOTE: the disable secure boot option does not appear until after you switch to UEFI. I was now able to turn Secure Boot Off. The way to do this was also on the BIOS menu. I simply scrolled left to the Security tab (NOTICE: you should see an option for Secure Boot on the Bottom. You need not disable this, since my next instruction will disable it). I scrolled all the way down to Reset to Setup Mode and pressed enter. This Clears PK, disables Secure Boot (see for yourself on that screen) and enters Setup Mode. On a side note: I tried simply disabling Secure boot many times, saving it each time but this did not change anything when I restarted my computer (still booted to Windows automatically).

After this, when I rebooted I had the option to choose Ubuntu or Windows (since Ubuntu was already installed).

I did this on a Lenovo P400. My understanding is that this whole UEFI thing is unique to new operating systems, including but not limited to Windows (8 and 8.1)

Comment: Don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-) (And *please* don't put "solved" in the title...  :-)