# Ubuntu 14.04 not booting grub-rescue

Tags: 14.04, boot

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04 and after installation and booting, a command comes  "grub-rescue". I tried sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair but it says "Temporary failure in name resolution".
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to boot ubuntu from grub-rescue by following instructions from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/159850/432944

Comment: I tried but I didnt get (hd0,msdos1) or (hd0,msdos2) instead I get (hd0) (hd0,gpt4), (hd0,gpt3), (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (fd0) (fd1) after typing ls command

Comment: Try to do the same, it doesn't matter if it's gpt partition table or msdos. Just type the ones you have, like `ls (hd0,gpt3)/`.
On the other side, it may be related to BIOS UEFI settings. Information from this post may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/536093/installing-ubuntu-14-04-grub-rescue-error-after-failing-to-turn-off-secure-boot

Comment: Again I faced the same problem, it showing "grub rescue>"

Comment: Strange, If you fixed it once, it should've stayed so. Did you do any changes in BIOS or grub afterwards? Anyway, you may try the same steps again that helped you for the first time.